# Como disparar um email automático através do Django quando receber um valor novo no banco de dados?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Olá, meu sistema está monitorando serviços de um servidor, quando um serviço falha eu recebo um novo valor no banco de dados com estatus "8" que significa erro, eu gostaria de mandar um email para algum usuário informando essa falha, já ouvi falar do signals do Django, porem, não faço ideá de como implementar isso.

Segue meu models.py

```
class Executionresults(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    taskid = models.UUIDField(db_column='TaskID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    executionid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutionID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    appid = models.ForeignKey(Apps, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='AppID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    executingnodeid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutingNodeID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status')  # Field name made lowercase.
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartTime')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use django-model-utils

```
pip install django-model-utils
```

Acresente um campo para fazer `tracking` em seu model, e sobrescreva o método `save`, sua classe ficaria assim:

```
from model_utils import FieldTracker

class Executionresults(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    taskid = models.UUIDField(db_column='TaskID')
    executionid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutionID')lowercase.
    appid = models.ForeignKey(Apps, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='AppID')  
    executingnodeid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ExecutingNodeID') 
    status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status')
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartTime')

    # Acrescente o campo abaixo
    tracker = FieldTracker(fields=['status'])

    # Sobrescreva o metodo save 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Cheque se o campo foi alterado 
        if bool(self.tracker.changed()):
            # Envie o email aqui

        # Salve os dados normalmente
        uper().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

No ponto indicado chame o codigo para o envio do email.

Voce pode também, ao invés de somente checar se o campo mudou, comparar como o valor do erro, nesse caso o metodo save ficaria assim:

```
    # Sobrescreva o metodo save 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Cheque se o campo recebeu o valor do erro 
        if self.tracker.changed()['status']==8:
            # Envie o email aqui

        # Salve os dados normalmente
        uper().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Para saber mais sobre FieldTrakcer, [acesse esse link.](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker)

> Editado (07/03/19) [Experimental]: Sobrepondo o metodo `__init__`

```
class Executionresults(models.Model):
    # ... Definição dos campos anteriores
    status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status')
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartTime')

    # Acrescente a variável abaixo
    __status_original = None

    # Sobrescreva o metodo __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Executionresults, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # guarde o valor do status 
        self.__status_original = self.status

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # Cheque se o campo foi alterado 
        if self.status != self.__status_original:
            # Envie o email aqui

        # Salve os dados 
        super(Executionresults, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__status_original = self.status
```

Comment: Funcionou Sidon, muito obrigado pela ajuda, gostaria de tirar mais uma dúvida, eu trabalho com mais de 2 bancos de dados diferentes, quando eu rodo essa função no models que está com o banco 'default' funciona perfeitamente, porem quando rodo em um models que está com postgree eu não recebo nenhum email e tambem não recebo nenhum erro, será que seria necessário especificar o banco de dados que é para ele verificar a alteração ?

Comment: Qual é o "banco default"? Ja tentou fazer um teste minimo somente com uma tabela em postrgres de teste?

Comment: O banco 'default' é o sqlite, já testei em uma tabela de teste no postgres e não rolou.

Comment: Estava testando algumas coisas e parece que ele funciona apenas quando eu edito o valor e clico em salvar no admin, assim ele reconhece no banco postgres, porem se esse valor vir do sistema ele não reconhece.

Comment: Ok, vamos tentar guardar o campo e comparar antes de salvar, vou editar a resposta mas nao tenho como testar, teste me diga se funciona.

Comment: Beleza Sidon, assim que você editar eu testo aqui, mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Editatdo, veja se funciona.

Comment: Sidon, testei e agora nem quando eu salvo ele dispara o email, agora fiquei mais curioso para saber o que possa estar ocorrendo.

Comment: Como eu disse não posso fazer o teste hoje, mas lembro-me que antes de postar a primeira opcao eu fiz o teste e, embora n tenha sido com postgres, não foi pelo admin e funcionou. Tente, ao invés de mandar um email, testar com um comando do tipo `print('Funcionou')` para ver o que acontece.

Comment: Testei aqui com postgres, funciona com as duas opcoes.